# Controlling progressbars of fragments from the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am working on android filebrowser project in which I am using TabLayout. It contains two sliding tabs. One is Images and another is Videos. I am trying to load the images and videos from device memory and put it in recyclerviews of Tabs. In the activity I load image and video files into two ArrayList using async task. and Fragments use them to load into Recyclerviews. But when app starts I want two progressbars to be visible in each tab. after it loads,progressbars should be Invisible.

fileselect.java:

```
      public ArrayList<String> imageset = new ArrayList<>();
      public ArrayList<String> videoset = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fileselect);

    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());

     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ftoolbar);
     toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textwhite));
     toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

     toolbar.setTitle("Selected: 0");
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

     tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.ftablayout);
     pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fpager);
     adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

     adapter.AddFragments(new Images(), "IMAGES");
     adapter.AddFragments(new Videos(),"VIDEOS");

     pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
     pager.setAdapter(adapter);

     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
     loader l = new loader();
     l.execute();

}

private class loader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    Images fragmentimage = (Images) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("imagestab");
    Videos fragmentvideo = (Videos) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("videostab");
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        fragmentimage.imageProgressOn();
        fragmentvideo.videoProgressOn();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getfile(root);


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        fragmentimage.imageProgressOff();
        fragmentvideo.videoProgressOff();

    }

}
```

Images.java:

```
       @Nullable
       @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.images, container, false);

    imageloadprogress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.imagesloadprogress);
    imageloadprogress.setIndeterminate(true);

    IRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.images_tab);
    IRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    ILayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    IRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(ILayoutManager);
    IAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(),((fileselect)getContext()).imageset);
    IRecyclerView.setAdapter(IAdapter);

    return v;

}
public void imageProgressOn(){
    imageloadprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void imageProgressOff(){
    imageloadprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
  }
```

Videos.java:

```
     @Nullable
    @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos, container, false);
     VRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.videos_tab);
     VRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    videoloadprogress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.videoloadprogress);
    videoloadprogress.setIndeterminate(true);

    VLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    VRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(VLayoutManager);
    VAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getContext(),((fileselect)getContext()).videoset);
        VRecyclerView.setAdapter(VAdapter);
    return v;
}
public void videoProgressOn(){
    videoloadprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void videoProgressOff(){
    videoloadprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

ERROR:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.sandesh.filer, PID: 18228
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sandesh.filer/com.example.sandesh.filer.NewFilebrowser.fileselect}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sandesh.filer.NewFilebrowser.Images.imageProgressOn()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sandesh.filer.NewFilebrowser.Images.imageProgressOn()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.sandesh.filer.NewFilebrowser.fileselect$loader.onPreExecute(fileselect.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                           at com.example.sandesh.filer.NewFilebrowser.fileselect.onCreate(fileselect.java:83)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: try invoking the async task in `onStart` instead of `onCreate`  i.e. `loader l = new loader();     l.execute();` in `onStart`

Comment: same error. Null pointer exception at Images.imageProgressOn().

Comment: post this method code `adapter.AddFragments(new Images(), "IMAGES");`.. because here I dont see where you are adding `tags`

Comment: I am adding tags directly in .xml file. Like this  android:tag="imagestab"